# Which MySQL database is my WordPress install using?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am working on a website for a client who has several websites on her web hosting account. I would like to move one of the websites, which is running on WordPress, to my localhost. But am having issues with the MySQL db and can't figure out which database the site is using.

The *wp-config.php* points to one database, but when I look at that same database in phpMyAdmin there are none of the common WordPress tables in there. Instead of the prefix `wp_` there are a bunch of tables with the prefix `cp_`. I don't know what that means. There are other databases on the client's hosting account that have WordPress tables, but the `wp_options` tables for them all point to other site URLs, not the one I'm trying to work on.

How can I find out which database is being used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible that the table prefix has been changed to `cp_` instead of the standard `wp_`. Some installations do that to mitigate some types of SQL injection attacks. `wp-config.php` should always point to the real database which, in your case, should have table names like `cp_posts`, `cp_postmeta`, `cp_options`, etc.

Check for the `$table_prefix` variable in the config file, or it may be buried in some cPanel option somewhere.

Comment: You are right about the prefix, the cp_options tables does reflect the site URL I am working on.